# How to connect to Livepeer to Rinkeby network?

Tags: ethereum

I want to run livepeer and for that I need it to get connected to an Ethereum network. There are two options as mentioned [here](https://livepeer.org/docs/installation/connect-to-ethereum):

- Hosted API services
- Self hosted Ethereum node

If I want to opt for the latter, how would I mention rinkeby?

Because I only want to use for the test purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial uses `geth` as example of the self-hosted Ethereum node.

In the geth [manual](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/command-line-options), you can find the `--rinkeby` option to connect your node to the Rinkeby network.

Example:

```
geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,web3"
```

*It seems that the Livepeer doc only shows 1 hyphen (`-`) for the `geth` options, but it really should be 2 (`--`).*

Don't forget to change the network option to `-network rinkeby` on Livepeer start as well.

Example:

```
livepeer -network rinkeby -ethUrl "http://localhost:8545"
```